# Download Youtube Video Chunks Using python

Tags: python, youtube

im trying to read youtube videos before the downloading process finish.

```
from pytube import YouTube

url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izFplWRNlnw"
yt = YouTube(url)
video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
video.download()
```

i want to access each chunk as .mp4 for example before the download completed.
VLC Player can play the uncompleted file data.

so how can i read each chunk of the progressive stream.